# Disable Visual Studio's insertion of single space before closing parenthesis in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, editor, parentheses

**Question**

I'm using Visual Studio 17 and my name is Emo.

When a man types the following into a .cs file:

```
new int[]{1
```

...and then types the closing parenthesis, an unwanted space is inserted, yielding:

```
new int[]{1 }
```

I spend a fair amount of time cleaning up these unwanted spaces. **How do I prevent this autoinsertion from occurring?**

**All spacing is turned off in Options**

For ye to visit the screen that lives within Tools >> Options >> C# >> Code Style >> Formatting >> Spacing, it is clear that all "Insert Space Before" and "Insert Space After" are turned off. Behold *all* options on this screen are unchecked.

**Editor Config and csharp_space_between_parentheses**

The newness of the thing does prevent myself from fully understanding the editor config file's purpose and it's precedence for the thing, but alas, I have uncovered an article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules) which makes mention of a special recipe known as `csharp_space_between_parentheses`. But again I am unable to use it.

Following the instructions indicated within a webpage known to us [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/1461), one might learn that with such a file, one of the following lines should solve the problem:

```
csharp_space_between_parentheses = none
csharp_space_between_parentheses = false
```

And yet again, neither of these lines solves the problem when embedded within the newly created file that people like to call `.editorConfig` that was added to the root of the project folder. Indeed, the problem persists.

We would truly appreciate your solve in this matter.

Comment: Hi, **Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Formatting->General** Turn off automatic formatting options. Does it help you?

Comment: Turn off the automatic formatting of ‘;’ and turn on brace completion, you can achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the visual studio "Smart" indent feature:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50937

You can switch indenting to None or Block under:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Indenting
```